# PageIndexChanging in gridview won't fire

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview, page-index-changed

I downloaded a free template from the internet and now I am using it in my project of ASP.NET. I have a gridview and I am using Paging but because of the template the PageIndexChanging event wont fire.

Now is there a alternate to this because my data in the gridview is very large and so the gridview is getting very long and out of my template. Can this event fire on a button click?

My .cs code is:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    emp();
}
```

Comment: might be a dumbquestion, Did you set it to allow paging ="True"

Comment: And are you always binding the data to the GridView? As you should be binding only `!IsPostBack`

Comment: yes i am

 if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            emp();
        }

Comment: and yes allow paging="true"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex= e.NewPageIndex;
    emp();
}
```

set the property in Aspx file........

```
    AllowPaging = true 
PageindexChanged = GridView1_PageIndexChanged
```

Comment: GridView1.CurrentPageIndex= e.NewPageIndex;
did not work its giving me a error on currentPageIndex 
it says that for the gridview doesn't contain a definition for CurrentPageIndex... 

plzz help